# Returning 2 values in a vb.net foreach

Tags: vb.net

I am new to vb.net and would like to return two values in a foreach, can you help me?

```
For Each item In Function ()
         test1 = I would like to get the result1 here
         test2 = I would like to get the result2 here
     Next

Private Function Function () As String
     Dim result1  As String
     Dim result2 As String

     result1 = "Test"
     result2 = "Test2"

     Return result1

End Function
```

Comment: Are you looking for a [tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: A KeyValuePair would be another solution. Or an array (of String). Or a list(of String) or, or, or...

Answer (score 1):

There is a ton of object that can fit that need..

- The [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to be what you are looking for:

  ```
  Return New Tuple(Of String, Of String)(result1 , result2)
  ```

But other solution like List, Array, Custom Class, KeyValuePair, ValueTuple

Answer (score 1):

Depend on how you will use your function.

You can return named ValueTuple [Tuples as method return values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples#tuples-as-method-return-values)

```
Private Function Get() As (One As String, Two As String)
    Return (One:= "one", Two:= "two")
End Function

Dim values = Get()
value.One ' one
value.Two 'two
```

You can create and return instance of own class

```
Public Class Values
    Public Property One As String
    Public Property Two As String
End Class

Private Function Get() As Values
    Return New Values With { .One = "one", .Two = "two" }
End Function

Dim values = Get()
value.One ' one
value.Two 'two
```

From performance point of view there not big difference, so make decision based more on readability and maintainability.

Class will be preferred approach in case where you using same return types in multiple places or you want pass it through to other functions.

Comment: Was editing all possibilities with exemple but this one is more logic than the other.